# Размеры окна в Java

Tags: ооп, gui, jframe, java, netbeans

Какое свойство класса MainWindow унаследованного от javax.swing.JFrame или метод возвращает размеры окна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тебе только вернуть значения размера окна? то вот:

```
System.out.println(frame.getSize().height + "   " +frame.getSize().width);
```

frame- это тво экземпляр JFrame, или если у тебя класс унаследован от JFrame, то писать нужно this.getSize..и т.д